# Filter rows based on multiple condition in where statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, where-clause

I have following table in Postgres 11.0

```
id              status
NCT00632827 true
NCT00632827 (null)
NCT00770185 false
NCT00770185 (null)
NCT00784303 (null)
NCT00784303 (null)
```

The id values are duplicated due to different value in status column. I would like to keep the rows with either true or false. If multiple rows have null value, I would like to keep only 1 row. The desired output is:

```
id              status
NCT00632827 true
NCT00770185 false
NCT00784303 (null)
```

I am trying following query:

```
select id, status
where status = 'false' or status  = 'true'
from table
```

How can I keep rows with null value (last row in the desired output)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this dataset, simple aggregation seems good enough to produce the expected results:

```
select id, bool_or(status) status from mytable group by id
```

Comment: In the output, rows with null are selected?

Comment: @rshar: for your sample dataset, this produces exactly the result that you asked for.

Comment: This answer should work, because NULL is ignored in aggregate functions. Otherwise, `FALSE OR NULL` gives NULL.

Comment: Above query suggested by GMB works perfectly. My actual data has 50 columns so in order to filter those duplicated rows, how should I give so many columns in group by clause